# malloc fails catastrophically

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am trying to implement a Queue in C. Coming from Java and other managed languages, I am really struggling with memory management. Here is the `enqueue()` function:

```
int enqueue(Queue q, int value) {

    Node newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    /*newNode->value = value;

    if (q->size == 0)
        q->head = newNode;
    else
        q->head->next = &newNode;

    q->size++;*/
}
```

I am getting this error :

```
malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

FWIW, here's the rest of the code (is this even right?):

```
typedef struct NodeStruct *Node;
struct NodeStruct {
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    int value;
};

typedef struct QueueStruct *Queue;
struct QueueStruct {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size;
    int capacity;
};

Queue newQueue(int size) {
    Queue q = malloc(sizeof(Queue));

    q->capacity = size;
    q->size = 0;
    q->head = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;

    return q;
}

void printQueue(Queue q) {
    printf("Queue of size %d, capacity %d", q->size, q->capacity);
}    

int main() {
    Queue myQ = newQueue(10);

    // this seems to work
    printQueue(myQ);
    // epic fail
    enqueue(myQ, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The problem happened way before that call to `malloc`, when you clobbered over the past of something allocated by an earlier call to `malloc` or with an uninitialized pointer. Good luck finding it.

Comment: Even though the code is commented out, I'll point out that `enqueue` is really wrong: it saves the address of a *local* variable (that shouldn't even compile), and it doesn't initialize the members of `Node`.  Also, adding something to a queue usually involves adding to the tail, not to the item after the head.

Comment: *Always* check the result of `malloc`! You can use a wrapper around it for this (search for [xmalloc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libiberty/Functions.html#index-xmalloc-202) on the Internet). If this is a homework please add the *homework* tag to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following line is probably giving you grief:

```
Node newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

`Node` is a pointer type, so you're only allocating enough space to hold a pointer, not an entire `NodeStruct`. I think what you want to do is:

```
Node newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
```

or

```
Node newNode = malloc(sizeof(NodeStruct));
```

The same issue exists for `Queue`, you're only allocated space to hold a pointer, not a `QueueStruct`. Something else that I only just noticed, is that in your `NodeStruct` and `QueueStruct`, you are using the type `Node*`, which is actually `NodeStruct **`, which is probably not what you want, since `Node` is already a pointer.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why it's often considered bad style to hide a pointer within a `typedef`.

Comment: @caf: he could have also used the infamous [Hungarian notation](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) properly, e.g. `Node` and `pNode`. It would have saved him a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 8):

It's often considered bad style in C to hide a pointer within a `typedef`.  This is because you *need* to know that something is a pointer to use it properly, anyway.  (For example, even the opaque type `FILE` in the standard library is used and passed around as a `FILE *`).

This seems to have led you astray - for example, your `next` and `prev` members are actually pointers-to-pointers, which is not really what you want.  I suggest:

```
typedef struct NodeStruct Node;
typedef struct QueueStruct Queue;

struct NodeStruct {
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
    int value;
};

struct QueueStruct {
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int size;
    int capacity;
};

Queue *newQueue(int size) {
    Queue *q = malloc(sizeof(Queue));

    q->capacity = size;
    q->size = 0;
    q->head = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;

    return q;
}

int enqueue(Queue *q, int value) {

    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (q->size == 0)
    {
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        q->tail = q->head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->prev = q->tail;
        q->tail->next = newNode;
        q->tail = newNode;
    }

    q->size++;
    return 0;
}

void printQueue(Queue *q) {
    printf("Queue of size %d, capacity %d\n", q->size, q->capacity);
}

int main() {
    Queue *myQ = newQueue(10);

    printQueue(myQ);
    enqueue(myQ, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you have trashed your heap

if you are on linux use electric fence or valgrind to find out where you went wrong

edit : you mean

```
Queue q = malloc(sizeof(QueueStruct));
```

and the same for node

```
Node n = malloc(sizeof(NodeStruct));
```

and I agree with others - its *very* misleading to call a pointer to a NodeStruct Node. Better to call it NodePtr or PNode and to call the struct Node.

Comment: -1, the problem is more fundamental than that, as dreamlax and caf have noted.

Comment: no its not - the naming is misleading but the fix is the same

Comment: Fair enough.  If you mention that the same problem exists for `Node` and `NodeStruct`, and explain why (remember the OP is coming from Java), I'll change to a +1.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - there you go, can I have my rep back pls :-)